# Jest does not find tests even if testMatch has matches

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest, bitbucket-pipelines

Using Jest in bitbucket pipelines, it doesn't find the tests and hence failed with the following error :

```bash
+ npx jest
No tests found, exiting with code 1
Run with `--passWithNoTests` to exit with code 0
In /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build
  12 files checked.
  testMatch: **/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x), **/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x) - 2 matches
  testPathIgnorePatterns: /node_modules/, /build/ - 0 matches
  testRegex:  - 0 matches
Pattern:  - 0 matches
```

**Locally my tests run fine.**

**Project structure :**

```
.
├── build
│   ├── coverage
│   └── js
└── src
    ├── account
    │   ├── account.ts
    │   └── account.test.ts
    ├── index.ts
    └── index.test.ts
```

**jest.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.(t|j)sx?$": "ts-jest",
  },
  moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "tsx", "js", "jsx", "json", "node"],
  coverageDirectory: "build/coverage",
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/", "/build/"],

};
```

Tests are launched using following npm script

```
"test": "jest --coverage",
```

Is it normal for Jest not to run the test it finds with `testMatch` ?

- Tried to switch from `testMatch` to `testRegex` without success
- Tried to add the path to src in the launch script (`npx jest ./src`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the problem was that bitbucket runs the pipelines in a folder called
`/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build`
My complete folder structure is then :

```
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build
                                  ├── build
                                  │   ├── coverage
                                  │   └── js
                                  └── src
                                      ├── account
                                      │   ├── account.ts
                                      │   └── account.test.ts
                                      ├── index.ts
                                      └── index.test.ts
```

Because of the `build` in the `testPathIgnorePatterns`, all the folder were ignored.
See the Jest doc about this : https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#testpathignorepatterns-arraystring

> These pattern strings match against the full path. Use the  string token to include the path to your project's root directory to prevent it from accidentally ignoring all of your files in different environments that may have different root directories. Example: ["/build/", "/node_modules/"].

The solution was to remove the `build` from  `testPathIgnorePatterns` and change a litle bit the testMatch (in my case a testRegex) :
`testRegex: ".*/src/.*\\.test\\.(t|j)sx?$"`

OR

To add `<rootDir>` in each `testPathIgnorePatterns` elements

```
 testPathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/node_modules/", "<rootDir>/build/"],
```